# 'NoneType' object is not iterable in Pytorch model testing part?

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I' m studying on a hyperspectral image with Pytorch model. When i want to test the model i got the "NoneType objectis not iterable" error. There is a window sliding on the image and I added it to the test part. Within the for loop, the batch values are getting None and I don't know how to fix it. I am attaching the working code below. Thanks for your help.

```
def test(net, img, hyperparams):

net.eval()
patch_size = hyperparams["patch_size"]
center_pixel = hyperparams["center_pixel"]
batch_size, device = hyperparams["batch_size"], hyperparams["device"]
n_classes = hyperparams["n_classes"]

kwargs = {
    "step": hyperparams["test_stride"],
    "window_size": (patch_size, patch_size),
}
probs = np.zeros(img.shape[:2] + (n_classes,))

iterations = count_sliding_window(img, **kwargs) // batch_size
for batch in tqdm(
    grouper(batch_size, sliding_window(img, **kwargs)),
    total=(iterations),
    desc="Inference on the image",
):
    with torch.no_grad():
        if patch_size == 1:
            data = [b[0][0, 0] for b in batch]
            data = np.copy(data)
            data = torch.from_numpy(data)
        else:
            data = [b[0] for b in batch]
            data = np.copy(data)
            data = data.transpose(0, 3, 1, 2)
            data = torch.from_numpy(data)
            data = data.unsqueeze(1)

        indices = [b[1:] for b in batch]
        data = data.to(device)
        output = net(data)
        if isinstance(output, tuple):
            output = output[0]
        output = output.to("cpu")

        if patch_size == 1 or center_pixel:
            output = output.numpy()
        else:
            output = np.transpose(output.numpy(), (0, 2, 3, 1))
        for (x, y, w, h), out in zip(indices, output):
            if center_pixel:
                probs[x + w // 2, y + h // 2] += out
            else:
                probs[x : x + w, y : y + h] += out
return probs

probabilities = test(model, img, hyperparams)
```

Then i got this error:

```
Inference on the image:   0%|          | 0/210 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-cabf8b6fa06d> in <module>()
----> 1 probabilities = test(model, img, hyperparams)
      2 prediction = np.argmax(probabilities, axis=-1)

<ipython-input-54-b248a53c93ce> in test(net, img, hyperparams)
        23         with torch.no_grad():
        24             if patch_size == 1:
   ---> 25                 data = [b[0][0, 0] for b in batch]
        26                 data = np.copy(data)
        27                 data = torch.from_numpy(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's the content of batch. It's not easy to find, but here some advice on how to get closer to the bug:

1. Python 3.10 has better error messages (shows where in the line the error is!)
2. try to enumerate() through batches and then find the defect index
3. use a try/expect (just temporary) to break on this ValueError and print out and inspect the whole batch
4. If it's not bad, that this specific batch is "none" you can skip it:

   `data = [b[0][0, 0] for b in batch]`

   becomes

   `data = [b[0][0, 0] for b in batch if b]`